# Add Default Rubberduck VBA Folder Annotation to VBProject.VBComponents

Tags: vba, excel, rubberduck, ms-access, powerpoint

Currently Rubberduck VBA files all the VBProject VBComponents in that do not have a Folder Annotation in a Folder named after the VBProject.  It can be time consuming to manually organize the components for the first time and a inconvenient to add annotations to every Worksheet, Userform, Class, ...ect.  When ran my code will organize any unfiled component by `ProjectName.ComponentType`.

**Before**

[image: Rubberduck Code Explorer - No Folders]

**After**

[image: Rubberduck Code Explorer - With Default Folder Annotations]

You will need to add a reference to the `Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3` and from file options check "Trust access to VBA project object model".

[image: Programmatic Access]

```
Private Sub AddDefaultFolderAnnotationsToVBComponents()
    Dim Component As VBComponent
    Dim Project As VBProject
    
    Select Case Application.Name
    Case "Microsoft Access", "Microsoft Word"
        Set Project = IIf(True, Application, 0).VBE.ActiveVBProject
            
    Case "Microsoft Excel"
        Set Project = IIf(True, Application, 0).ActiveWorkbook.VBProject

    Case "Microsoft PowerPoint"
        Set Project = IIf(True, Application, 0).VBE.VBProjects(1)
        
    End Select
    
    Dim FolderName As String
    Dim HasFolder As Boolean
    
    For Each Component In Project.VBComponents
        With Component.CodeModule
            If .CountOfLines = 0 Then
                HasFolder = False
            Else
                HasFolder = InStr(.Lines(1, .CountOfLines), Chr(39) & "@Folder")
            End If
        End With
        
        If Not HasFolder Then
            Select Case Component.Type
                Case vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule
                    FolderName = Project.Name & ".Modules"
                Case vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_ClassModule
                    FolderName = Project.Name & ".Classes"
                Case vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_MSForm
                    FolderName = Project.Name & ".Forms"
                Case vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_ActiveXDesigner
                    FolderName = Project.Name & ".Designers"
                Case vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_Document
                    FolderName = Project.Name & ".Documents"
            End Select
            
            Component.CodeModule.InsertLines 1, Chr(39) & "@Folder(""" & FolderName & """)"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Note: I purposely kept all the functionality in a single procedure for portability.

Kudos to the Rubberduck team the latest version [Rubberduck VBA v2.5](https://rubberduckvba.com/) is a C# WPF that follows the MVVM pattern to the letter!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111999/discussion-on-question-by-tinman-add-default-rubberduck-vba-folder-annotation-to).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> HasFolder = InStr(.Lines(1, .CountOfLines), Chr(39) & "@Folder")
> ```

That condition can *technically* be `True` in modules that don't *actually* have the annotation; a `@Folder` Rubberduck annotation is only valid in a module's *declarations section*, so there's no need to grab the module content any further than `.CountOfDeclarationLines` - if the module is nearing the 10K lines capacity, using this instead of `.CountOfLines` could make a significant difference in the size of the string being passed to the `InStr` function.

> ```
> Select Case Component.Type
>     Case vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule
>         FolderName = Project.Name & ".Modules"
>     Case vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_ClassModule
>         FolderName = Project.Name & ".Classes"
>     Case vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_MSForm
>         FolderName = Project.Name & ".Forms"
>     Case vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_ActiveXDesigner
>         FolderName = Project.Name & ".Designers"
>     Case vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_Document
>         FolderName = Project.Name & ".Documents"
> End Select
> ```

I wouldn't repeat the concatenation here - just work out the last part of the name per the component type, and *then* concatenate with `Project.Name & "."` (I'd pull the separator dot out of the `Case` blocks as well) - and then I might give it a bit of breathing room, but that's more subjective:

```
    Select Case Component.Type
        Case vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule
            ChildFolderName = "Modules"

        Case vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_ClassModule
            ChildFolderName = "Classes"

        Case vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_MSForm
            ChildFolderName = "Forms"

        Case vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_ActiveXDesigner
            ChildFolderName = "Designers" 'note: not supported in VBA

        Case vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_Document
            ChildFolderName = "Documents"

    End Select
    FolderName = Project.Name & "." & ChildFolderName
```

I like the `@Folder("Parent.Child")` syntax and I see that's what you're generating here:

> ```
> Component.CodeModule.InsertLines 1, Chr(39) & "@Folder(""" & FolderName & """)"
> ```

Note that this would also be legal... and simpler to generate:

```
Component.CodeModule.InsertLines 1, "'@Folder " & FolderName
```

Obviously if you prefer the parenthesized syntax (either works, it's really just down to personal preference) like I do then by all means keep it, but Rubberduck's new *Move to Folder* command doesn't put the parentheses in. I'd probably have the single-quote `'` character spelled out, too, but I can see how a `'` might be harder than necessary to read in the middle of a bunch of `"` double quotes. On the other hand, defining a constant for it would remove the need to have the `"@Folder` string literal defined in multiple places:

```
Private Const RD_FOLDER_ANNOTATION As String = "'@Folder "

...

Component.CodeModule.InsertLines 1, RD_FOLDER_ANNOTATION & FolderName
```

I have to mention that Rubberduck *deliberately* shoves all modules under the same default named-after-the-project folder (they can easily be sorted by component type in the *Code Explorer*), because we **strongly** believe grouping modules by component type is utterly useless and counter-productive: when I look at the code for a given functionality, I want to see all the code related to that functionality - and I couldn't care less about the component type of the code I'm looking at... it's mostly all class modules anyway.

A *sane* way to organize the modules in a project, is by *functionality*: you want your `ThingView` user form in the same place as your `ThingModel` class and your `ThingPresenter` and the `Things` custom collection - that way when you're working on that *Thing*, you don't have to dig up the various pieces in an ever-growing list of components under some useless "Class Modules" folder.

Comment: I really like the `ChildFolderName`, the extra white-space really cleans up the `Select Case`.  I didn't not realize the parenthesis were optional.   `Chr(39)` is the module that the `AddDefaultFolderAnnotationsToVBComponents` is in will not be skipped.

Comment: I disagree about categorizing by type being useless.  This is how MVC Bootstraps folder structure are typically organized `Project, Project.Views`, `Project-Models`, `Project.Controllers`.  Recommended Websites  layout are usually structured by `Root`, `Root.Css`, `Root.JS`,`Root.Php`...etc.  Having a default filing system also makes it easier to re-organize your folders because you will not have all the documents without code-behind cluttering up the place.   A drop down to change folder views would go along way to making your point

Comment: Eureka!  Only checking the declaration portion would eliminate the need for `Chr(39)`!!

Comment: What do you think about allowing multiple folder annotations? This would allow us to associate worksheets with more than one set of files.

Comment: Multiple folder annotations would result in... source files showing up in multiple places in the code explorer? How should we handle this? As for MVC default namespaces/folders, it's not the same thing at all because namespaces *may or may not match/follow the folder structure* (although it would be recommended that they do), ...and there is no distinct folders for `Classes`, `Interfaces`, `Enums`, `Structs`, `Delegates`, ...nor should there be any! You'll also find various blog posts about whether the default MVC project structure is useful...

Comment: ...the conclusion I've drawn boils down to *use the default structure because otherwise you're going to be fighting VS... and you will want to avoid that*. But yes, perhaps a CE view matching the vanilla-VBE by-component (but still drill-down to member level) folders could be useful... I would just find it a bit sad I guess, if users mostly just picked that view over the fully-customizable one where their *actual* project structure can *really* pop out.

Comment: Hey Matt, the OP has added an "ADDENDUM". Not sure if you've seen it but I'll leave you to handle it however you think is best since you seem to be around.

Comment: From a purist standpoint, I agree with your arguments.   But in practice, I will work on a project for 1 to 3 hours and never see it again.  That is the main reason that I want to filter out the documents without code, instead of filing them.

Comment: @TinMan Peilonrayz is correct - including the updated code in the OP makes it kind of implicitly feel like the case is closed and no other input would be considered; that's why we encourage you to put the updated version in a new/follow-up "question" if you want additional feedback on the updated code. Basically we're all about the *review* and what good comes out of it - often the "final" result is never quite *final* anyway, ..for many of us anyway ;-)

Comment: You and @Peilonrayz are right.  I know better.  I might come back to this at a latter date.  I don't like the fact that the code will not work on hidden projects.